# Translating CURL to Golang code

Tags: http, curl, go

I'm trying to execute this exact CURL command in Golang:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "WEB2PY-USER-TOKEN: token-string" -d '{"rfrID": "111111"}' 'url-string'
```

It's a little weird because it's a GET HTTP call with a JSON body. Our vendor however requires us to call the API like this though. I can't figure out how to make our Golang program execute this API.

This is the Go code that I've tried so far:

```
data := Payload{
    // fill struct
    RfrID: "111111",
}
payloadBytes, err := json.Marshal(data)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
body := bytes.NewReader(payloadBytes)

log.Printf("[INFO] Input body status: %v\n", body)

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "url-string", body)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
req.Header.Set("Web2py-User-Token", "token-string")

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}

log.Printf("[INFO] Artemis status: %v\n", resp)

defer resp.Body.Close()
```

In my logs the following gets printed:

```
2017/10/10 07:31:56 [INFO] Input body status: &{[123 34 114 102 114 73 68 34 58 34 49 49 49 49 49 49 34 125] 0 -1}
```

I expect this body to be a JSON body like:

```
{"rfrID": "111111"}
```

Comment: Show what have you tried so far.

Comment: This might be of use: https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/

Comment: Thanks I've added more code and tried that link but still haven't figured it out yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your body is what you think it is, it is just printed in an unexpected format to you.

[`bytes.NewReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader) returns a pointer to the struct type [`bytes.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Reader). When you print it using [`log.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Printf), it uses the formatting rules defined in the package doc of [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/), that is, pointers to struct are printed as `&{}` and values of fields enumerated inside of it. This is what you see. `bytes.Reader` stores the data it provides in a byte slice:

```
[123 34 114 102 114 73 68 34 58 34 49 49 49 49 49 49 34 125]
```

And this byte slice is equivalent to the JSON string you expect. To verify:

```
data := []byte{123, 34, 114, 102, 114, 73, 68, 34, 58, 34, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 34, 125}
fmt.Println(string(data))
```

Output:

```
{"rfrID":"111111"}
```

Reading from this reader will provide this exact string, as you can see in this example:

```
r := bytes.NewReader(data)
fmt.Println(r)
readData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
if err != nil {
    panic(r)
}
fmt.Println(string(readData))
```

Output:

```
&{[123 34 114 102 114 73 68 34 58 34 49 49 49 49 49 49 34 125] 0 -1}
{"rfrID":"111111"}
```

Try these examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1qUNAx8QtC).

### Differences

Let's examine the differences between the CURL command and the client you wrote, with this little app which will be the target:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    log.Println("Method:", r.Method)
    log.Println("Headers:", r.Header)
    log.Println("Form:", r.Form)
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    log.Println("Body:", data, err)
    log.Println("Body string:", string(data))
})
panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

CURL:

```
2017/10/10 10:17:26 Method: GET
2017/10/10 10:17:26 Headers: map[Content-Length:[19] User-Agent:[curl/7.47.0] Accept:[*/*] Content-Type:[application/json] Web2py-User-Token:[token-string]]
2017/10/10 10:17:26 Form: map[]
2017/10/10 10:17:26 Body: [123 34 114 102 114 73 68 34 58 32 34 49 49 49 49 49 49 34 125] <nil>
2017/10/10 10:17:26 Body string: {"rfrID": "111111"}
```

Go client:

```
2017/10/10 10:17:20 Method: GET
2017/10/10 10:17:20 Headers: map[User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Content-Length:[18] Content-Type:[application/json] Web2py-User-Token:[token-string] Accept-Encoding:[gzip]]
2017/10/10 10:17:20 Form: map[]
2017/10/10 10:17:20 Body: [123 34 114 102 114 73 68 34 58 34 49 49 49 49 49 49 34 125] <nil>
2017/10/10 10:17:20 Body string: {"rfrID":"111111"}
```

Despite some headers added automatically by the clients, and a space inside the JSON string (which has no effect just formatting), they are identical.

Comment: My CURL command however is a GET command. It works with the JSON body and returns me the expected result. I'm 100% sure the vendor's documentation states a GET with the stated body.

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans Added test to show differences. Beside some insignificant differences they are identical.

Comment: Thanks icza! Makes complete sense now.